# Android: strings resource, multiple strings with the same name

Tags: android, string, resources, repeat

In strings.xml

Lets say I have the following strings:

```
<string name="CourseInfo">Course Information</string>
<string name="CourseInfo1">Course Information:</string>
<string name="CourseInfo2">Course Information:-</string>
```

As you can see the string is the same, the only difference is that the second one has a colon and the third one has a colon and a dash.

Is this the most optimal way to do this? It seems kinda repetitive to do it this way.

Comment: Do it programatically when needed. `getResources.getString(...) + ":-" ;` or `+ ":";` ?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri Is that the only way to do it?

Comment: No idea. Lets wait for other answers. If there is an another way I would be glad to know :)

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use some thing like

```
<string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>
```

see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

so for your example

```
<string name="CourseInfo2">Course Information%1$s</string>
```

and then

```
Resources res = getResources();
String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.CourseInfo2), ":");
String text2 = String.format(res.getString(R.string.CourseInfo2), ":-");
```

Comment: this doesn't consider localization that would be necessary for a different language